# Problem using multiple Python checkers with Syntastic in vim

Tags: python, vim, syntastic

I set up multiple checkers in my `.vimrc` file but it seems it has no effect. When I save my file I have auto check enabled so I get only flake8 checks, how is that?
This is my `SyntasticInfo` output:

```
Syntastic version: 3.10.0-22 (Vim 802, Darwin)
Info for filetype: python
Global mode: active
Filetype python is active
The current file will be checked automatically
Available checkers: flake8 mypy pep8 pycodestyle pyflakes pylint python
Currently enabled checkers: flake8 pylint mypy
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I installed Syntastic with Vundle and these are my settings in `.vimrc` file:

```
let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['flake8', 'pylint', 'mypy']
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
```

How do I know that only flake8 checks are being performed? Well, I have another small window that opens up with the checks and at the bottom of it it says: `:SyntasticCheck flake8 (python)`

I have all these linters installed correctly in my python env from which I write my code files.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: `:help 'syntastic_aggregate_errors'`